# getting an alert no XML document returned for XSLT request below

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing

this is an empty xml document for which i am generating a response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EmptyResult xmlns="http://www.tandberg.com/XML/CUIL/2.0" product="TANDBERG     Codec" version="TC7.1.1.168aadf" apiVersion="2"/>
```

this is the code for response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//objects"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="objects">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is the XML in your question the input to the transform? What are you expecting for output and what are you getting?

Comment: ohk i am expecting the output should be nothing because we donot have any data in xml, but it is generating the alert as "no response or xslt request". so i need some code to be added in the response so that the alert shouldnot come.

Comment: i am expecting no alert if my xml is returning empty response after transforming into xslt

Comment: The output _IS_ nothing, as the message is telling you.  If you need it to be "something that means 'nothing' to the server" we can't help you with that until you determine from the server's API documentation what it wants for empty input.  We have no idea what API you are talking to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't directly XSLT related, but a question of your XSLT processor. Depending on what you use (Java, .net, PHP, Ruby etc.) you get different error messages when your output doesn't yield a result.

There are several steps you can take:

- handle the error in your code. After all your stylesheet doesn't do its job
- fix the stylesheet to include an output for an `<EmptyResult` tag too
- While you are on it: `select=//` is a performance killer for large outputs

Hope that helps